# How to declare a function prototype and its parameter declaration list?

Tags: c, c99, function-declaration, function-parameter

As I read ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 6.9.1 -> EXAMPLE 13

And the note:

```
extern int max(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

[...]

```
extern int max(a, b)
int a, b;
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

> Here int a, b; is the declaration list for the parameters. The difference between these two definitions is
>   that the first form acts as a prototype declaration that forces conversion of the arguments of subsequent calls
>   to the function, whereas the second form does not.

So I wrote my own test code to compile it that way. (I figgured out, both ways would need to be declared before or had to ahve an prototype with the type definition mentioned anyway)

```
size_t foo (size_t a, size_t b);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /*some call to foo*/
    return 0;
}
```

So I'm asking now: is there any performance related difference between this way:

```
size_t foo (a, b)
size_t a, b;
{   
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

and this one?

```
size_t foo (size_t a, size_t b)
{   
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Because as I understood it, there is a difference, because the first way avoids multiple conversions at function call, as it says there has to be no conversion to the parameter type, as it's guaranteed the type will be of type (in this case) `size_t`.

But I was confused as I figured out, the prototype has to look similar in both cases and I thought the prototype is the source where the compiler takes his treatment from.

So: whats the difference exactly? and if there is one, why is the first way so rarely (never) seen?

Comment: @Dayal rai But the c99 standard says the first way supresses conversions, what would mean less action on runtime, or did I get that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this:

```
size_t foo (a, b)
size_t a, b;
{   
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

means that if you now call it like this:

```
int x = 3;
int y = 4;

foo(x,y);
```

The arguments will not be converted to `size_t` before being passed to the function.  This means you'll get undefined behaviour (assuming `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)`).  And the compiler won't warn you.  That's why no-one does this in practice.

Comment: That's what i got so far. So as I'm pretty sure about I will never have anything different parsed in then size_t comatible types, I can do so and will have probably performance icnrease won't I?

Comment: @Zaibis: No performance increase.  Whichever form you use, a `size_t` will not undergo a conversion.

Comment: ok, but if we go away from size_t would there be anyway in which we could get performance icnrease on this way, doesn't matter whcih type we have?

Comment: @Zaibis: No.  If you supply a different type, then a conversion **needs** to be done.  But the `size_t foo (a, b)` form will **not** perform a conversion.

Comment: Ah, ok now I got it, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is an old ISO standard. It's not used any more in any production code, but you may still find it in some legacy code. I doubt there is any difference between the two excepting the syntax.

Comment: There is more difference than just new and old and syntax. Per C 2011 6.5.2.2 6, “If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double.…” (As noted in 6.2.7 3 a prototype is a function declaration with a parameter type list, “a function type with a parameter type list (a function prototype)”. A function declaration with an identifier list, rather than a parameter type list, is not a prototype.)

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
size_t foo (a, b)
size_t a, b;
{   
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

of defining functions comes from K&R C, So you may encounter this in older books and programs.
C89 and C99 support this style. Programmers avoid using it in new programs for a couple of reasons.

First, functions that are defined in the older way aren't subject to the same degree of error checking. When a function is defined in older way- **and no prototype is present**- the compiler won't check that the function is called with the right number of arguments, nor will it check that the arguments have proper types. Instead, **it will perform the default argument promotion**.

Second: **6.11.6 Function declarators** says

> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
>   type declarators) is an **obsolescent** feature

Comment: can you show me a source, where is said that the "older" style is obsolescent?

Comment: And where? as I read jsut some minutes ago the altest version of the c99 standard about functions where I was moved to ask this question. and ther wasn't anything said about one of theese both styls is obsolescent.

Comment: Have you read the link I have provided above? Where have you read this as a **latest** version? Give me the link.

Comment: yeah, but what microsoft does in view of the c language is just a bad joke as they aren't even supporting main features of c99. the MSVC2013 compiler is still based on c89 and is more mixed with c++ as you could imagine. So microsoft isn't the source I would care about if they tell something from the c standard is obsolescent, as far it doesn't is written in the standard too. Don't get me wrong, but microsoft doesn't even have a compiler which is respecting the c standard, so if they say it is obsolescent to their compiler that doesn't even had to mean anything.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer that **C standard** says that it is obsolescent. I never mention MSDN site says.  I gave that link only because I did't find where it is in the standard.

Comment: thats ok so far, but you should take that link out, as msdn is realy not a satisfying source to the standard, specially if they are jsut talking about their compiler. Either I'm not satisfyed that this is obsolescent untill I can see it written in the standard.

Comment: Where you have read that it is C99's latest version? Please give me the link. I am asking you again.

Comment: @Zaibis: See section 6.11.6 and 6.11.7.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; Forget that link. I have added C standard to the answer.